# Rails process taking too long to respond

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

When I am sending a a GET request to rails server it takes too long time to respond   (29 minute)

Below is the log snippet

Log says that there is an error in code, it is ok, but why take so long to respond (1723579 ms)  I am unable to find any reason of such kind of behavior. Previously when server was working fine this js request only take 9 ms to respond. but suddenly it started to behave like this. How should i debug the application to trace the root cause of such unexpected behavior.

```
        Started GET "/my-server/jobs/workers?_=1356363515400" for 27*.*.*.* at 2012-12-24 21:08:35 +0530
    ActionView::Template::Error ():
             1: <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
             2:   $('#cron_<%= job.id %>').attr('data-content', '<%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(job.next_fire_info, true) %>');
             3: <% end %>
             4: 
             5: <% @workers.each do |worker| %>
           app/models/job.rb:16:in `next_fire_info'
           app/views/jobs/workers.js.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_jobs_workers_js_erb__101155230_81985760'
           app/views/jobs/workers.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_jobs_workers_js_erb__101155230_81985760'


 Rendered jobs/workers.js.erb (1718348.7ms)

 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1723579ms
```

I am on Rails 3.1.3, 
Ruby 1.9.3p194, 
MongoDB version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5, 
32 bit Ubuntu (12.04) with 2 gb ram

Comment: What version ? There was a bug in some versions of 3.2.x (and I think 3.1.x) where producing the error message accidentally called inspect on the app which was unnecessary and very slow

Comment: My application contains 5 tab, out of which other 4 tab are working fine, problem only in this "Job" tab. and it was working fine  earlier but suddenly this amount of delay is introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have found the reason for taking so long time to respond. The workers are running periodically based on cron expression.Root cause of this particular issue is one cron expression for job was entered erroneously. that's why at the time of  executing "distance_of_time_in_words_to_now" took too much time.

Answer (score 0):

Versions of rails 3.1 before 3.1.5 have a bug whereby when an exception is raised from a view rails takes a very long time to generate the exception message.

If you can't update to 3.1.5, the fix is very simple (see the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bef0b354e49b67b0953f5c6e83a6f54fc812fef5) that fixes it) - you just need to monkey patch inspect:

```
module ActionDispatch
    module Routing
        module RouteSet
          alias to_s inspect 
        end
    end
end
```

I used to dump this in an initializer. There's also a gem (safe_inspect) that claims to do this for you although I never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it was caused by authentication, so this is just for record if someone has the same problem in the future. The server did not let the user in and then redirected to the page which was restricted as well etc. etc.